# How to create an XMLConfiguration on demand

Tags: java, apache-commons-config

I'm using commons-configuration 1.10 and would like to have my configuration file created only when needed.

For now, I have

```
        XMLConfiguration config= new XMLConfiguration(file);
        config.setReloadingStrategy(new FileChangedReloadingStrategy());
        config.setAutoSave(true);
```

But, when I try to call

```
        config.setProperty("portal.0.name", portal.getName());
```

I get

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified. 
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration.createDocument(XMLConfiguration.java:914)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration.save(XMLConfiguration.java:1034)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractHierarchicalFileConfiguration$FileConfigurationDelegate.save(AbstractHierarchicalFileConfiguration.java:570)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.save(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:557)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.save(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:524)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.save(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:474)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.save(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:441)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.save(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:418)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.possiblySave(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:749)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified. 
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.createElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration$XMLBuilderVisitor.insert(XMLConfiguration.java:1529)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.HierarchicalConfiguration$BuilderVisitor.visitBeforeChildren(HierarchicalConfiguration.java:1734)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.HierarchicalConfiguration$Node.visit(HierarchicalConfiguration.java:1401)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.HierarchicalConfiguration$Node.visit(HierarchicalConfiguration.java:1407)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration$XMLBuilderVisitor.processDocument(XMLConfiguration.java:1504)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration.createDocument(XMLConfiguration.java:908)
    ... 37 more
```

Which seems to indicate file can't be saved by autosave mechanism.

So, is there something I do bad ?

And how can I create the configuration while creating the file only when needed (cause otherwise it will require some weird XML file copy)

Comment: This looks like a bug, I suggest opening a ticket in JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CONFIGURATION.

Comment: @EmmanuelBourg do you mean I'll need to switch to 1.09 or 2.0-alpha ?

Comment: @EmmanuelBourg bug can be reproduced using 1.9. And I have no ASF account, sorry ... I'll have to find a workaround, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `portal.0.name` where I should have used `portal(0).name`, which was solved by ... well ... reading [the doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide_v1.10/howto_xml.html#Accessing_structured_properties).